# Is it possible to write our own rpm -e option?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have created a rpm build which will extract files as part of  rpm installation then run custom scripts to install the package. But when i do rpm -e option it will remove only the rpm  extracted files which is not good enough. How can i write rpm -e option to run my custom uninstall script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom `%preun` or `%postun` scriptlet.

That being said, what you are doing is **wrong** and not following the philosophy of what RPMs are supposed to do. You've made it nearly impossible for an admin to verify the integrity of the files on the system (`rpm -V`), find out what installed the files on the system (`rpm -q --whatprovides`), etc. **Please reconsider.**

Answer (score 0):

In a normal scenario, where files are created as a by-product of your package life-cycle (i.e. log files, temporary files), you can have these removed during uninstallation using the `%ghost` directive.  See [Directives For the %files list](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html) .

In your `%files` section you would `%ghost` own these additional files.   Packaging would not attempt to include these files in the rpm, but upon uninstallation of your package, it would recognize ownership, and remove them accordingly.

```
%files
%ghost /var/log/mylogfile.log
```